# Django: Adding values globally to admin context

Tags: django, django-admin

In the header of the django admin, I want display a link. This link should only be visible to users of a specific group (and for the link, I need some additional data to reverse it).

How can I add this values globally to the context used in django admin templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write an [inclusion tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) that renders the link.

If you include the `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth` template context processor, you will be able to access `user` in the context.